# How to get all of relational records using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

the table like this:

```
id | userid |   contentid
-------------------------
41 |   92   |     1187
42 |   92   |     1189
43 |   92   |     1190
44 |   92   |     1193
45 |   92   |     1200
46 |   92   |     1201
47 |   92   |     1202
48 |   104  |     1200
49 |   104  |     1201
50 |   104  |     1202
51 |   103  |     1200
52 |   103  |     1201
53 |   103  |     1202
```

and i am trying to get all the related content ids with 1202(e.g.).

1. I would take all the users who have added this content grouped.
2. After grouping the records according to the content IDs except 1202, the
   number of groups have to sort by.

shortly i want to get the following list:

```
1201 - count: 3
1200 - count: 3
1187 - count: 1
1189 - count: 1
1190 - count: 1
1193 - count: 1
```

I tried a query like the following to be the way I want, but more needs to be done other things.

```
(from x in IRepository<ContentRelation>().Query().ToList()
    where x.Content.Id == content.Id
    group x by x.GUser.Id into c
    select new
    {
      a = c.Key,
      b = (from d in IRepository<ContentRelation>().Query()
           where d.GUser.Id == c.Key && d.Content.Id != content.Id
           select d)
    })
```

Edit:
i got what i want with those following queries but im not sure this is right way:

```
var q = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository<ContentRelation>>().Query();

List<int> gh = new List<int>();

foreach (var item in q.Where(x => x.Content.Id == content.Id).GroupBy(x => x.GUser.Id).Select(x => x.Key))
{
    foreach (var a in q.Where(x => x.GUser.Id == item && x.Content.Id != content.Id).ToList())
    {
        gh.Add(a.Content.Id);
    }
}

foreach (var hhj in gh.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()))
{
    Response.Write(hhj.Key + "-" + hhj.Count()+ "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With that you got what you want (in theory :) )

```
IRepository<ContentRelation>().Query().GroupBy(x => x.Content.Id).Select(x => new Tuple<int, int>(x.Key, x.Count())).OrderBy(x => x.First)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = IRepository<ContentRelation>().Query()
                                           .GroupBy(p => p.contentid)
                                           .Select(p => new
                                           {
                                               contentid=p.Key,
                                               counter=p.Count()
                                           });
```